# Timer: See an alert on  another view controller when time is up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, timer

In my timer application,

My timer runs on oneViewController.

When I switch to another view without any efforts it runs in background of another view 
as I press the back button I can see the results..

But,
I want to put an alert message on second view controllerwhen my time is Up.....

How could I do this...

**Should I use

-Delegate

-Notification

-Local Notifications**

Or else.....Thanks

**EDIT: Answer:**

**Answer is in first comment...****

Comment: You can make your timer call a method on your view controller. In that method, you can check if time is up. If so, create an UIAlertView, because that is visible from the entire application

Comment: That's Great....I have never thought that simple..thanks....

Comment: Could you explain me I have presented view so,how could it shows the alert as I have set it on another view...pls

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but if you ask why it is possible: an UIAlertView creates a new UIWindow and adds itself above any other window. It will be omnipotent in your app :)

Comment: NP :) can you pls accept/upvote my answer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6101/discussion-between-h2co3-and-arpit-parekh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your timer call a method on your view controller. Inside that method, you can check whether time is up. If so, create an UIAlertView instance and -show; it as it will be shown/seen from any view controller.